# Expectation of Girsanov transformation

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, expected-value

I want to compute $\mathbb{E}[(B_n+n)^3\mathrm{exp}(-B_n-n/2)]$, where $B_n$ denotes the one dimensional discrete Brownian motion.

Clearly $\mathrm{exp}(-B_n-n/2)$ is a Girsanov transformation, thus it seems as it would natural to use this somehow. But I am very uncertain as to how to proceed. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $B_n\sim N(0,n)$,
\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}(B_n+n)^3e^{-B_n-n/2}&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(x+n)^3e^{-x-\frac{n}{2}-\frac{x^2}{2n}} \,dx \\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(x+n)^3e^{-\frac{(x+n)^2}{2n}} \,dx  \\[1em]
&=\mathsf{E}(Z+n)^3=\ldots,
\end{align}
where $Z\sim N(-n,n)$.

Comment: So then $Y=Z+n \sim N(0,n)$ and thus $\mathbb{E}[Y^3]$ should equal to the third moment of a $N(0,n)$-distributed random variable (i.e. $0$)? Is this correct?

Comment: @lognormal That's correct.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!